# Conformal mapping of a doubly connected domain onto an annulus

Tags: complex-analysis

It is a well known theorem that any doubly connected domain can be conformally mapped onto an annulus.

Consider the simpler version :

Suppose $D$ is a bounded domain whose boundary is two non-intersecting circles. Then $D$ can be conformally mapped onto an annulus.

I believe that the proof of this should be easier, that the conformal map would be just a linear fractional transformation. However, I'm having trouble constructing it. Could someone help?

Thank you

Comment: Side question: is a double connected domain doubly connected because there are *two* ways of getting from each point to another?

Comment: @Mariano : Doubly connected usually means that the complement has two components (think of an annulus, for example), as opposed to simply connected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose your outer circle is the unit circle $C_1=\{z:|z|=1\}$.
All you have to do is to get a linear fractional transformation
taking $C_1$ to itself and the inner circle $C_2$ to a circle centred
at the origin. You might as well rotate $C_2$ so that its centre
is on the real axis. Then $C_2$ meets the real axis in points $a$ and $b$
with $-1 < a < b < 1$. The required linear fractional transformation
will have real coefficients and take $-1$, $a$, $b$, $1$ to $-1$,
$-c$, $c$, $1$ where $0 < c < 1$. The typical linear fractional transformation
fixing $-1$ and $1$ has the form
$$f_u:z\mapsto\frac{z+u}{uz+1}.$$
We are considering $u$ real and for $u$ to take the unit disc to itself,
$|u| < 1$. We need $f_u(a)=-f_u(b)$. This is a quadratic equation in $u$ with two
real roots, one of which satsifies $|u| < 1$.