Question Regarding the Solution to Problem 5.3.3 in the Berkeley Problems in Mathematics Book
The problem states: A fractional linear transformation maps the annulus $r < |z| < 1$ (where $r<0$) onto the domain bounded by the two circles $\left|z-\frac{1}{4}\right| = \frac{1}{4}$ and $|z|=1.$ Find $r$.
The solution given is: Let $A = \{z : |z| < 1, |z-1/4| > 1/4\}$ and $B = \{z : r < |z| < 1\}$ Let $f(z) = (z-\alpha)/(\alpha z - 1)$ be a linear fractional transformation mapping $A$ onto $B$, where $-1< \alpha < 1.$ We have $f(\{z: |z-1/4|=1/4\}) = \{z: |z| = r\},$ so $\{f(0),f(1/2)\} = \{-r,r\}$ and $0 = r-r = f(0) + f(1/2) = \alpha + \frac{1/2 - \alpha}{\alpha /2 - 1}$ which implies $\alpha = 2- \sqrt{3}$. Therefore $r = |f(0)|= 2-\sqrt{3}$.
Suppose now that $g$ is a linear fractional transformation mapping $C = \{z : s < |z| < 1\}$ onto $A$. Then $g^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$ is a straight line through the origin, because the real line is orthogonal to the circles $\{z: |z-1/4|=1/4\}$ and $\{z: |z| = 1\}$. Multiplying by a unimodular constant, we may assume $g^{-1}(\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{R}$. There $f\circ g (C)= A$ and $f\circ g (\mathbb{R})= \mathbb{R}.$ Replacing, if necessary, $g(z)$ by $g(s/z)$, we may suppose $f\circ g (\{z: |z| \leq 1\}) = \{z: |z| \leq 1\}$, so $f\circ g(z) = \beta \frac{z-\alpha}{\overline{\alpha}z-1}$ with $|\alpha| < |\beta| = 1$. Using the relation $0 = f(s) +f(-s)$, we get $\alpha = 0$, so $f \circ g(z) = \beta z$ and $ s = r = 2- \sqrt{3}.$
To me, the problem appears to be solved in the first paragraph of the solution. What is the purpose of the second paragraph? I'm not sure why the solution proceeds with the function $g.$ It seems like an alternate proof of the result, but there is no written indication that the authors are presenting an alternate proof. Also, shouldn't it be $f\circ g (C)= C,$ not $f\circ g (C)= A$?

Hmm.  I am not sure one can automatically assume that the unit circle  of A is necessarily mapped to the unit circle of B.  Note that inversion can flip large and small circles.

@MathFont Regarding that, I saw this post (the signs in the linear fractional transformation are a bit different, but the computation still worked out to give $r = 2 - \sqrt{3}$): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4665/conformal-mapping-of-a-doubly-connected-domain-onto-an-annulus

Yes.  I think the wording in the first solution is flawed because it makes the assumption that unit circle is mapped to unit circle and then deduces some conditions that $r$ would then need to satisfy. The second paragraph then seems to show that one can WLOG arrange to satisfy the hyp of the first paragraph. The exposition is not structured very clearly.
